# How do you reference the current selector as in jquery's $(this) within dart

Tags: dart

Dart uses `query('#selector')`

if i wanted to get a reference to the result so i can do something with the selected item, what is the dart equivalent. I tried `query(this)` but

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Document.query(selector)`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html.html#query) function is not an equivalent of [`jQuery(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) but an equivalent of [`Document.querySelector(selector)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector). Thus you cannot get the selector used and you have to keep the reference aside.

If you want to use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) in Dart you can use it with the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).

Comment: I wish people stopped suggesting jQuery in Dart :)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use `jQuery(this)` or `$(this)` for the purpose of retrieving the target of an event:

```javascript
$('.foo').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).hasClass('bar'));
});
```

In Dart you can write that like:

```dart
query('.foo').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
  print(e.target.classes.contains('bar'));
});
```